# Can we add a 'recently viewed' to the Users pane

Tags: feature-request

The users pane let's us see our own questions, answers, comments, tags, badges votes etc.

It would be really nice if we could also see the most recent posts we viewed.

There have been so many occasions I've looked for something to find it, forget to mark it as favorite and close the browser (typically by mistake) and then not be able to re-find the page (even via Google).

If the SE sites could keep a track of just the last few pages I visited, this would be great.

Comment: I like this idea.

Comment: This would probably garner a pretty good reception at meta.SE - +1

Comment: @Dave - I totally agree with this improvement.  I have been there, done that, eventually given up finding the question I was looking for.

Comment: Ha, brilliant! @JourneymanGeek get's more upvotes for liking my idea than I do for suggesting the idea!!

Comment: Hmmm....I thought that browser bookmarks handles this type of situation.  If you don't like that, organize your links via Evernote or M$ OneNote.

Answer (score -1):

I find this a bit pointless. The site is good as it is and adding more features like this would just clog up the interface.

I don't see this feature as an absolutely necessary but rather as a good-to-have for some advanced users.

I would recommend to use your browser history for that purpose. Does the job perfectly for me. Just use "`superuser.com`" as a filter and you will get your most recently visited pages.

You can also look at improving your browser history with one of the existing addons. For Chrome addons see [Are there any advanced options for Google Chrome's history search?](https://superuser.com/q/352970/281154)

Comment: So the website is good.  This means they should fire all the developers and never change another line of code right?  This suggestion is good and I have been in the same boat.  Even more so, I have viewed a question on Device A then wanted to view the same question on Device B but was unable to find it.  This would be extremely easy to add, why should we be stuck with a specific browsers functionality, one many people can't even use half the day.